# What is /Volumes/firmwaresyncd?

Tags: efi, firmware, hacking

I keep seeing this in my logs:

```
> 10/5/15 3:45:16.532 AM deleted[366]: normalizeUserMountpoint:738
> volRoot failed for /Volumes/firmwaresyncd.G3PNKw
```

What is it? Is it related to [the firmware 0day hack from July](https://reverse.put.as/2015/05/29/the-empire-strikes-back-apple-how-your-mac-firmware-security-is-completely-broken/)?

I'm on 10.11, 2012 mbp.

Comment: What does `ls -ld /Volumes/firm*` return?

Comment: Quick explanation: `firmwaresyncd runs at boot time to synchronize the firmware file(s) from the root filesystem to the EFI System Partition (ESP).`       
_(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/firmwaresyncd.8.html)_ - I don't think that it's related to the firmware hack, at least I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: I agree this is disturbing. I found it running after I woke the computer from sleep and I found this volume. /Volumes/firmwaresyncd.61c316

Answer (score 2):

The `firmwaresyncd` system is Apple designed and expected to run at all normal boots. Perhaps the system didn't unmount it once the check was complete.

If you restart your Mac, I've not seen it stay mounted twice in a row, and if you get it always sitting, a support call to Apple might be in order to be sure your firmware is updated if you are running OS updates when asked to. I don't think it's cause for concern immediately, but making sure you would be prompted if you were out of date is a good thing to double check that your security and patches are up to date.